# downloading csv file using postForm function in R

Tags: r, csv, post, rcurl, downloading-website-files

I am trying o download csv data from the web using postForm, however, the file downloaded seems to be a html document instead of a csv file.
These are my code:

```
############################
library(RCurl)

url <- "https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/MKTGDPSAA646NWDB/downloaddata"
params <- list(
  "native_frequency" = "Annual", units = "lin",
  "frquency" = "Annual", "aggregation" = "Average", "obs_start_date" = "1968-01-01",
  "obs_end_date" = "2014-01-01", "file_format" = "csv", "download_data_2" = "", format="csv")

result <- postForm( url, .params = params)
writeBin(as.vector(result),"doc2.txt")
```

Comment: I see both misspellings and a lack of concordance of the script names with your names. Spend more time reviewing the code on the page.

Comment: I used your recommended code but still have the same result

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the encoding

Comment: I doubt it. I still see an obvious misspelling and the names on your form submission do not match the names in the code. The submit button has names: `id="form_download_data_2"` and `name="form[download_data_2]"`

Comment: This is the php code that worked

Comment: $post_data = "form[native_frequency]=Annual&form[units]=lin&form[frequency]=Annual&form[aggregation]=Average&form[obs_start_date]=$start_date&form[obs_end_date]=$end_date&form[file_format]=xls&form[download_data_2]=";

Comment: I see! I should not have removed the form[],I though that should be removed.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more modern approach is to use the `httr` package:

```
library(httr)

res <- POST("https://research.stlouisfed.org/",
            path="fred2/series/MKTGDPSAA646NWDB/downloaddata",
            body=list(`form[native_frequency]` = "Annual", 
                      `form[units]` = "lin", 
                      `form[frequency]` = "Annual", 
                      `form[aggregation]` = "Average", 
                      `form[obs_start_date]` = "1968-01-01", 
                      `form[obs_end_date]` = "2014-01-01", 
                      `form[file_format]` = "csv", 
                      `form[download_data_2]` = ""),
            write_disk("doc2.txt"))

warn_for_status(res)

##         DATE       VALUE
## 1 1968-01-01  4187777711
## 2 1969-01-01  4485777644
## 3 1970-01-01  5377333333
## 4 1971-01-01  7184853037
## 5 1972-01-01  9664157065
## 6 1973-01-01 14947391339
```